# Getting the latest value in subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a subscription that will grab a "status" of an overall line the status's are pending-validated-completed, these are checked in the API and updated in the DB.

I have a method that will update a behavioursubject with this status. there are several components subscribed to the behaviour subject as the status effects certain parts of the webpage.

```
private statusSubject= new Subject();
 CurrentStatus$ = this.statusSubject.asObservable();

 getStatus(id: number) {
   return this.client.getStatus(id).pipe(
     tap((x) => this.statusSubject.next(x)),
   );
 }
```

However, for me to get the latest status, I need to fire off another getStatus.subscribe() to update the behaviour subject. Is this correct? I thought that subscribing once will retreive the emitted values when there are changes? as a "active stream".

Comment: Why don't use a service who takes cares of that, so that all `getLatestStatus` calls are handled by the service (who knows whether or not to perform the first check), and share that service to all your components.

Comment: I'm confused, do you need to poll for a status change here or something?

Comment: please share your service code, as dcg mentioned you need to `pipe` it in your service

Comment: the service is generated by Nswag. the "client" and what the code I am showing is in my "service" which is a layer on top

Comment: @dcg this is in a service, its just I want to know if calling a subscribe to get the latest status is best practice... these subscriptions can build up when making a lot of changes

Comment: @bryan60 I have updated the question, All I want is the latest status after i preform an update, create or delete to ANY line. the way I am currently acheiving this is subscribing to the getStatus event which is in my service that updates the behaviour subject and 4 other components get this emitted value.

I am asking is this the best way to go about this? as the subscriptions will pile up...

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? Based on your comments.

Service:

```
deleteLine(id: number) {
    return this.client.deleteLine(id);
}

getStatus(id:number) {
    return this.client.getStatus(id);
}
```

Component:

```
this.someService.deleteLine(1).pipe(
    tap(line => this.line = line),
    flatMap(line => this.someService.getStatus(line.id)))
    .subscribe(status => this.status = status); //or whatever you need to do in subscribe, if anything
```

Comment: this is kind of what I am doing now, except the i am calling Subscribe in the subscription of deleting a line and not in the service, this would basically be the same result, which feels weird? unless this is how it is done?

I am new to front-end so these concepts confuse me

Comment: Updated based on your comment!

Comment: so, when I do a create/update will I follow the same logic? 

I was expecting subscribing to the getStatus endpoint would update when it detects a change in the backend. is it normal to need to keep fetching this endpoint?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, and the back-end is just a regular API, you don't magically get realtime updates from an API just by using .subscribe(). If you want to listen for a change that is happening on the back-end, you'd need to either do what you are doing, poll on an interval, or look at a server -> client messaging framework like SignalR, or a real-time database such as Firebase Firestore.

Comment: ah right, whats the best way to handle subscriptions? if i keep it how i currently have it it will build it a good amount of active subscriptions until i destroy the component (i loop through the subscriptions there and unsubscribe) would a "takeuntil" be worth using?

Comment: takeUntil is almost always worth using for cleanup of subscriptions! Create a subject that specifically gets called on destruction of the component to cleanup all subscriptions, or have more specific subjects if you want to destroy a set of subscriptions earlier.

Answer (score 0):

so this seems like a state management / app architecture question more than anything else.

Generally, you seem to have some general app state that could be described like:

```
{
    latestStatus: Status;
    lines: Line[];
}
```

and it seems that creating / updating / deleting a line has a side effect of changing the status, so that side effect needs to occur, so how to do that?

I would structure it like this, so my StatusService would look like:

```
private statusSubject= new Subject();
CurrentStatus$ = this.statusSubject.asObservable();
private updateStatusSubject = new Subject<number>();

constructor() {
  this.updateStatusSubject.pipe(
    switchMap(id => this.client.getStatus(id))
  ).subscribe(this.statusSubject);
}

updateStatus(id: number) {
   this.updateStatusSubject.next(id);
}
```

and then my theoretical LineService would do something this:

```
constructor(private statusService: StatusService) {}

updateLine(id, data) {
  return this.client.updateLine(id, data).pipe(tap(() => this.statusService.updateStatus(id)));
}
```

this ensures the ordering of thing and keeps things at the service level rather than cluttering components, the view doesn't need to be aware of when the status needs to update, only the service. It also ensures everything happens in the correct order and that subscriptions are managed internally by the switchMap operator so there is only ever one active.  You'll want stuff like, error handlers and all that, you could add in `distinctUntilChanged()` or `debounceTime()` or whatever as well in this scheme, so you have more flexibility.

Comment: This seems like a more elegant way of doing this, will doing the `   this.updateStatusSubject.next(id);`  refire a subscription? or will it use the current active one?

Comment: it will trigger a new inner subscription in the switchMap, but do to the nature of switchMap, previous "in flight" subscriptions are cancelled so only one is ever active at a time

Comment: ah right, sounds a lot better. thanks! will add this.

Comment: the other benefit here is that it guarantees the "active" subscription is always the LATEST one to trigger the subject, whereas your prior setup could have some odd race conditions in it.